# Android button onClick() is slow

Tags: android, button, click, screenshot

that takes screenshot from the device screen. It take several seconds before and action will be perfomed and toast message with animation will appear. 
Here is my code:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
            v.startAnimation(animAlpha);
            try {
                Toast.makeText(GlobalTouchService.this, "Start process", 5000).show();
                Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
                OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();
                os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                sh.waitFor();
                Toast.makeText(GlobalTouchService.this, "Screenshot captured", 5000).show();
            } catch (IOException io){
                io.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie){
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I can't use bitmaps here. I don't care about slow action, but I want to display something after click immediately (because I want to know that button is clicked). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) when doing lots of work.

```
 /// your button click event
 public void onClick(View v) {
   new TakePrintScreen ().execute();
  }


 private class TakePrintScreen extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {
    private ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Information",
                "Please Wait.. ", true);
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
           v.startAnimation(animAlpha);           
         Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
        OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();
        os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        sh.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Tag, e.getMessage().toString());
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your code and display the Toast message out of try catch block.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
            // put toast here
            Toast.makeText(GlobalTouchService.this, "Start process", 5000).show();
            v.startAnimation(animAlpha);
            try {

                Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
                OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();
                os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                sh.waitFor();
                Toast.makeText(GlobalTouchService.this, "Screenshot captured", 5000).show();
            } catch (IOException io){
                io.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie){
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: This really shouldn't have any effect on speed.